# On WebdriverIO TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, class, testing, inheritance, webdriver-io

on WebdriverIO a constructor is not working, it gives the error: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Base class:

```
class BaseComponent {   
    constructor(rootSelector){
        this.rootSelector = rootSelector;
    }
    /**
    * Opens a div that contains all the phone cards
    */
    // setRootSelector(rootSelector){
    //     this.rootSelector = rootSelector;
    // }

    get rootElement(){        
        return $(this.rootSelector);
    }
}
module.exports = new BaseComponent();
```

Card class, the one that inherits:

```
const BaseComponent = require('../common/base.component');
//const {BaseComponent} = require('../common/base.component').default;
/**
* Class that handles the cards of the phones
*/
class CardComponent extends BaseComponent{   
    // constructor(rootSelector){        
    //     super(rootSelector);
    // }
    constructor(){
        super(`//div[@id='tbodyid']`);
        //super('//div[@id="tbodyid"]');     
        //BaseComponent.setRootSelector(`//div[@id='tbodyid']`);           
    }
    
    /**
    * Opens a div that contains all the phone cards
    */
    // get rootElement(){        
    //     return $(`//div[@id='tbodyid']`);
    // }  

    productLinkText(productName){                
        return this.rootElement.$(`//a[contains(text(),'${productName}')]`);
        // this.element = {rootElement: this.rootElement};
        //return this.element.$(`//a[contains(text(),'${productName}')]`);
        //return BaseComponent.rootElement.$(`//a[contains(text(),'${productName}')]`);
    }
}
//module.exports = new CardComponent(`//div[@id='tbodyid']`);
module.exports = new CardComponent();
```

All the commented code is what I have tried based on posts.

The main idea es to put on the base class the root of the component.

When the two classes are on the same file, the tests works.

Answer (score 2):

After an entire morning with this, this is the solution:
module.exports = BaseComponent;

No new and  ( ).